# while loop in c#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, average

I have this code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _121119_zionAVGfilter_Nave
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int cnt = 0, zion, sum = 0;
            double avg;
            Console.Write("Enter first zion \n");
            zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (zion != -1)
            {
               while (zion < -1 || zion > 100)
            {
                Console.Write("zion can be between 0 to 100 only! \nyou can rewrite the zion here, or Press -1 to see the avg\n");
                zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

                cnt++;
                sum = sum + zion;
                Console.Write("Enter next zion, if you want to exit tap -1 \n");
                zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            }
            if (cnt == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("something doesn't make sence");
            }
            else
            {
                avg = (double)sum / cnt;
                Console.Write("the AVG is {0}", avg);

            }
       Console.ReadLine(); }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that if in the beginning I enter a negative or bigger than hundred number, I will get this message: "zion can be between 0 to 100 only! \nyou can rewrite the zion here, or Press -1 to see the avg\n". 
If I then meenter -1, this what that shows up instead of the AVG: "Enter next zion, if you want to exit
  tap -1 \n."
How can I solve this problem so when the number is negative or bigger than hundred  and than tap -1 I will see the AVG an not another message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a flag variable and it's done.

```
namespace _121119_zionAVGfilter
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cnt = 0, zion, sum = 0;
        double avg;
        int flag = 0;
        Console.Write("Enter first zion \n");
        zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (zion != -1)
        {                 
            while (zion < -1 || zion > 100)
            {
                Console.Write("zion can be between 0 to 100 only! \nyou can rewrite the zion here, or Press -1 to see the avg\n");
                zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if(zion== -1)
                    flag = 1;
            }                
            cnt++;
            sum = sum + zion;
            if (flag == 1)
                break;
            Console.Write("Enter next zion, if you want to exit tap -1 \n");
            zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (cnt != 0) { }

        }
        if (cnt == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("something doesn't make sence");
        }
        else
        {
            avg = (double)sum / cnt;
            Console.Write("the AVG is {0}", avg);                
        }            
        Console.ReadLine(); 
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, can you fix the problem without add another variable?

Comment: Yes, that i wrote just for your understanding. You can replace the "if (flag == 1)break;" with "if(zion== -1) break;" and remove the flag variable

Comment: Thank you but i'm a school student and I don't know what "break" means, the main prblem is that if I enter number which is bigger than hunderd os snaller than -1 , and if I prees  -1 that is happend " 'cnt++;
                sum = sum + zion;
                Console.Write("Enter next zion, if you want to exit tap -1 \n");
                zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());'" instaed of colculate the avg, why?

Comment: Break is used to break the loop's eg foreach, do while and while. And for other as you mentioned in your comment i'll say you are printing the avg out side the while loop, this whole code you can manage properly once you got the concept of loops and if's. Day by day after practicing more you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose this code that you don't want to be executed in `if` statement like this

```
if(zion != -1)
{
      cnt++;
      sum = sum + zion;
      Console.Write("Enter next zion, if you want to exit tap -1 \n");
      zion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      if (cnt != 0){}
}
```